# Fixing a 4 nested for loops in Python

Tags: python, python-3.5, nested-loops

So i'm trying to implement the agglomerative clustering algorithm and to check the distances between each cluster i use this:

```
a, b = None, None
c = max
for i in range(len(map)-1):
    for n in range(len(map[i])):
        for j in range(i+1, len(map)):
            for m in range(len(map[j])):
                //dist is distance func.
                d = dist(map[i][n], map[j][m])
                if c > d:
                    a, b, c = i, j, d
print(a, ' ', b)
return a, b
```

map looks like this: { 0: [[1,2,3], [2,2,2]], 1: [[3,3,3]], 2: [[4,4,4], [5,5,5]] }

What I expect from this is for each row item to compare with every row/col of every other row. So something like this:

comparisons:
[1,2,3] and [3,3,3], [1,2,3] and [4,4,4], [1,2,3] and [5,5,5], [2,2,2] and [3,3,3] and so on

When I run this it only works 1 time and fails any subsequent try after at line 6 with KeyError.
I suspect that the problem is either here or in merging clusters.

Comment: What does  `map` look like?

Comment: `map` is a reserved word in Python, so is `max`

Comment: also `//this is not a comment` but `#this is a comment`

Comment: map is a dict with lists of 3d int points as values

Comment: Sorry, I added that comment here for clarity

Comment: Check out [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `map` is a `dict` of values, you have a general problem with your indexing:

`for m in range(len(map[j])):`

You use `range()` to create numerical indices. However, what you need `j` to be in this example is a valid key of the dictionary `map`.

EDIT: 
That is - of course - assuming that you did not use 0-based incremented integers as the key of `map`, in which cause you might as well have gone with a `list`. In general you seem to be relying on the ordering provided in a `list` or `OrderedDict` (or `dict` in Python3.6+ as an implementation detail). See `for j in range(i+1, len(map)):` as a good example. Therefore I would advise using a `list`.

EDIT 2: Alternatively, create a list of the `map.keys()` and use it to index the `map`:

```
a, b = None, None
c = max
keys = list(map.keys())
for i in range(len(map)-1):
    for n in range(len(map[keys[i]])):
        for j in range(i+1, len(map)):
            for m in range(len(map[keys[j]])):
                #dist is distance func.
                d = dist(map[keys[i]][n], map[keys[j]][m])
                if c > d:
                    a, b, c = i, j, d
print(a, ' ', b)
return a, b
```

Answer (score 0):

Before accessing to map[j] check is it valid or not like:

```
if j in map.keys():
     #whatever
```

or put it in try/except:

```
try:
   #...
except KeyError:
   #....
```

Edit:
its better to use for loop like this:

```
for i in map.keys():
    #.....
```

Comment: so you have to check map[i] to. generally , when ever you want to access dictionary by key, you should check if the key exist or not OR put it on try/except .